# SSH and Telnet Connection refused

Tags: server, ssh, connection, telnet

If I am trying to ssh or telnet to an Ubuntu Server, and both connections are rejected or refused!

I can ping the server, firewall off.

What are troubleshooting steps should I take?

(I am far away from the Server, so console solution isn't available).

Comment: Similar issue for me on my VirtulBox Guest ubuntu happening. Ping working, telnet to ssh port 22 is working but when I have started WebLogic server it is not able give access, connfection refused. What is the solution for this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: check if service are listening on that ports use this command "netstat -ntlp"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine if programs on the server are listening to the `ssh` and `telnet` ports (22 and 23, usually), by:

```
nmap -T4 -A -v -PE -PS22,23 -PA22,23 <ServerIP>
```

or,

```
telnet <ServerIP> 22  
telnet <ServerIP> 23
```

If your error message is: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` the problem is on the remote server (no program is listening to that port). It's not running the telnet or ssh daemon,or running them on non-standard ports

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your telnet daemon and ssh is running in ur remote system.

In ubuntu ,

To enable telnet daemon, "sudo apt-get install telnetd"
To enable ssh client and server ."sudo apt-get install ssh-connection"